# How to check if Windows VPS is connected using Delphi?

Tags: delphi, remote-desktop

I have a VPS running on AWS Lightsail and i connect on it via Remote Desktop Connection.

There are some Delphi apps installed on this VPS and i only want to run them if is there someone connected on it at the moment. The machine is always running, but i need to know if at the moment is there somebody connected to it.

Is there a way to check this using Delphi 11 ?

Comment: As far as I know it is possible to schedule windows task to be fired when someone connects to windows computer using RDP connection. So you could use this to detect when someone connects. But I'm not sure about detecting disconnects.